# MapReduce filter before reduce

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, reduce

I have a Hadoop MapReduce Job that splits documents of different kinds (Places, People, Organisations, Algorithms, etc...). For each document I have a tag that identify the type of document and links to other documents, however I don't know which kind is the document of the link until the page of the link is reached in the task.

In the Map phase I identify, the links and the kind of the current page and then Emmit as values the information of the links and the current document with his tag to a single reducer, Key NullWritable Value "CurrentDoc::Type::Link".

In the reducer phase it is grouped all the documents by type using the "CurrentDoc::Type" of the values, and then emit a relation between "Document::Link" of only ones that belongs to certain Types.

However I have a memory issue because all the final step is performed only in one reducer.

It is a way, to perform a grouping task after the map process and before the reduce task for identify all the documents with its tags and then distribute them to different reducers.

I mean group all document/tag as "CurrentDoc::Type" in an ArrayWritable Text. Then emit to reducers as key the "CurrentDoc::Link" tuple and as value the ArrayWritable to perform some filtering in the reduce phase in a parallel way.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you use combiner function? Seems like it will be a good fit here.

Comment: Hi @JackDaniel's, well i read about combiners and the problem is that the combiners only process the data of one mapper and cannot process the data of all the mappers, that is what i need. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Just try sending the "CurrentDoc::Link" as the key and  "CurrentDoc::Type" as the value from the mapper itself.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the system does not work in the way you expect.

We can't change Mapper,Reducer & Combiner functionality.

> Hadoop allows the user to specify a combiner function to be run on the map output, and the combiner function’s output forms the input to the reduce function. In other words, calling the combiner function zero,one, or many times should produce the same output from the reducer.

Combiner can't combine data from multiple maps. Let's leave the job to Reducer.

For your problem,

1) Use **Customer Partitioner** and decide which reducer should be used to process a specific key (**CurrentDoc::Type**)

2) **Combiner** will combine the data with-in a **Mapper**

3) Outfrom **Mapper** will be redirected a specific Reducer depending on Key Partition (***shuffling***)

4) **Reducer** will combine data for key received from respective Mappers

[image: Combiner]

[Working code of](http://blog.puneethabm.in/custom-partitioner-in-mapreduce-using-new-hadoop-api-2/)  Partitioner & Combiner